# Impossible to read SD card on laptop

Tags: sd-card

I have 2 SD cards (16GB et 32GB, both FAT32) and 2 laptops.
On the first laptop (xubuntu 14.04), I can read both cards
On the second laptop (xubuntu 16.04), I can read the 16GB card but not the 32GB card.

So I'm guessing it's a problem with my card reader

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

the result of dmesg is sometimes:

```
[ 1787.645325] mmc0: tuning execution failed
[ 1787.645339] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SD card
```

and sometimes:

```
[ 1813.854024] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR50 SDHC card at address e624
[ 1813.854882] mmcblk0: mmc0:e624 SL32G 29.7 GiB 
[ 1813.855927] mmcblk0: unknown error -5 sending read/write command, card status 0xb00
[ 1818.853135] mmc0: tuning execution failed
[ 1818.853145] mmc0: tried to reset card
[ 1818.853152] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0
[ 1818.853158] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1818.854286] mmcblk0: unknown error -5 sending read/write command, card status 0xb00
[ 1818.854296] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0
[ 1818.854304] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1818.855013] mmcblk0: unknown error -5 sending read/write command, card status 0xb00
[ 1818.855023] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0
[ 1818.855029] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1818.855049] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1818.858837] Dev mmcblk0: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1818.859506]  mmcblk0: unable to read partition table
[ 1820.061592] mmcblk0: error -110 sending status command, retrying
[ 1820.061790] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x900, card status 0x800b00
[ 1820.661753] mmcblk0: error -5 sending status command, retrying
[ 1820.661879] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x900, card status 0x900
[ 1820.666399] mmcblk0: unknown error -5 sending read/write command, card status 0xb00
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

That card reader hates that particular SD card & just won't read it. Or sometimes it gives errors (that could corrupt the card too).

Stop using them together.

Try a good USB card reader instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's more probable the SD card is borderline, the second laptop's reader seems to be less tolerant of noise to signal ratio / damaged connector / manufacturing fault / environmental damage, etc.

For both readers I'd recommend getting a can of compressed air with a narrow straw tube and blow out the reader socket. They are not used often on most laptops and can hold a lot of dust leading to poor connections.

For the card that's working intermittently, I'd toss it, or clearly label it a junk card not for normal use.